# Encoding database utf-8 or utf-16

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, utf-8, utf-16

I am importing a database from outside which have unicode characters as 我的上网主页 and 嶏紞鎴戠殑 in Chinese , Japaneses and other different languages.

I have executed a query to make my database encoding to utf-8 from

```
ALTER DATABASE DEFAULT CHARSET 'utf8';
```

But when i import data to my database tables i get ????? instead of above characters.
How can i encode these characters? Is it utf-8 or 16 and how i can recognize that which encoding will support these characters?

Any Idea will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Both UTF-8 and UTF-16 will support all Unicode code points, so the problem lies elsewhere and is probably specific to your particular database or client. Which DBMS are you using? How exactly are you "importing"?

Comment: I am using MYSQL and i am importing using data by using a tool which is in python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL uses UTF-8. Make sure you had configured the connection character set properly, the way
of the configuration depends on the connectivity library you are using.

Comment: please tell me how can i check that ?

Comment: @Astha what client do you use? Programming language?

Comment: i am using PHP with MYSQL DB Server. I found that instead of my query above db is having charset as `latin1` only.